# sticky footer flexbox looses background color on chrome when widow expand

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a tree column flexbox sticky footer with a background color.
This footer 'loose' its background color when the content of the website overflow the window (so when it has to 'move' down).
The issue happens on chrome and opera but not Firefox.

Here is some code to reproduce the problem:

Press the button to toggle the expansion

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById('filling');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
}

footer {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <button id='button'>add some filling</button>
  <div>there should be enough filling to overflow the window (so that the footer has to move)</div>
  <div id='filling' style='display: none;'>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling<br/><br/><br/>filling</div>
</section>
<footer>
  sticky footer is a flexbox
</footer>
```

Comment: just remove display flex in footer.......

Comment: check it https://jsfiddle.net/rdcLhj6c/1/

Comment: This is an example ... I actually need a tree column footer.

Comment: Have you made code like three footer ?

Comment: Yes.. same problem happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add a `min-height` to your footer to prevent the height from being changed:

```
footer {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

it fixes your problem. Your footer height is set to 0 when your javascript is executed. Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yonxrpw4/1/

Comment: Is it specific to chrome ?

Comment: should work in Firefox/IE (depending on what version of IE)

Comment: I mean as this doesn't happens in firefox... Is it an issue with chrome or just a normal behaviour ? Thanks anyway, I'll do with your solution.

Comment: @Sylvain just improved my solution. it seems as though you have to set the `flex-shrink` property to prevent the height from changing. I'm not sure if it's chrome-specific but it's good practice to have it there regardless to prevent unwanted behavior

Comment: Perfect :-) Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Sylvain no problem